# jQuery, passing variable while using on({}) function

Tags: jquery, bind, blur

Say I have

```
$('body').on({
    click: function(){
        var myVar = 1;
    },
    blur: function(){
        // want to use myVar here
    }
},'.myDiv');
```

How do I pass myVar from click() to blur()? I don't want to use 
    $(this).bind('blur, function(){ // do what ever });

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

if you need separate state of different `.myDiv` elements then use

```
$('body').on({
    click: function(){
       $(this).data('myVar', 1);
    },
    blur: function(){
        var myVar = $(this).data('myVar');
        // want to use myVar here
    }
},'.myDiv');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the scope of the `myVar` variable:

```
var myVar;
$('body').on({
    click: function(){
        myVar = 1;
    },
    blur: function(){
        // Use myVar here to kill an alien
    }
},'.myDiv');
```